# How to output maximum

Tags: sql, database

I'm just trying to understand how to use max and count for my queries. I have the following code:

```
 SELECT SERVICE, COUNT(*)
 FROM SUBSCRIBERS INNER JOIN SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS ON
 SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS.LINE=SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID
 GROUP BY SERVICE;
```

Which outputs:

```
3WC|12
CFB|17
CWT|20
DSP|16
MSG|25
```

But I only want to output the maximum (MSG|25). I would also like to know how to output according to a specific condition (>15). I'm just not sure how to use the functions count and max at the same time.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `max` here - you can simply limit the number of rows returned and use `order by`.

Depending on the rdbms you are working with the syntax may very, but the idea is still the same:

For SQL Server, MS Access, and probably some more databases, use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SERVICE, COUNT(*)
FROM SUBSCRIBERS 
INNER JOIN SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS 
    ON SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS.LINE=SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID
GROUP BY SERVICE
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

For Oracle, use `offset...fetch next` (also works with sql server starting from version 2012)

```
SELECT SERVICE, COUNT(*)
FROM SUBSCRIBERS 
INNER JOIN SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS 
    ON SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS.LINE=SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID
GROUP BY SERVICE
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

For MySql, use `Limit`:

```
SELECT SERVICE, COUNT(*)
FROM SUBSCRIBERS 
INNER JOIN SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS 
    ON SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS.LINE=SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID
GROUP BY SERVICE
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
LIMIT(1)
```

Comment: In mysql, how would you specify that COUNT(*) is a certain value like 20. I've tried adding WHERE COUNT(*) = '20'.

Comment: You use the `Having` clause after the `group by` clause - `...group by service having count(*) = 20...`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific database vendor, you might be able to do this:

```
SELECT SERVICE, CNT FROM (
 SELECT SERVICE, COUNT(*) AS CNT
 FROM SUBSCRIBERS INNER JOIN SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS ON
 SERVICE_SUBSCRIBERS.LINE=SUBSCRIBERS.PORTID
 GROUP BY SERVICE
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CNT DESC
```